# Django GIS и leaflet, как конвертировать zoom в radius?

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, nuxt.js

На клиенте я по умолчанию выставляю `zoom` равный 13:

```
  <no-ssr>
    <l-map
      :zoom="13"
      :center="[coordinates.lat, coordinates.lng]"
      :options="options"
    >
      <l-tile-layer
        url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <l-marker
        v-for="marker in markers"
        :key="marker.id"
        :lat-lng="[marker.lat, marker.lng]"
      >
        <l-popup>{{ marker.popUpText }}</l-popup>
      </l-marker>
    </l-map>
  </no-ssr>
```

Но на стороне сервера я не хочу получать ВСЕ точки на карте:

```
Place.objects.all()
```

А хочу получить те, которые находятся в радиусе видимости пользователя, как-то так:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance  


lat = 52.5
lng = 1.0
radius = 10
point = Point(lng, lat)    
Place.objects.filter(location__distance_lt=(point, Distance(km=radius)))
```

Вопрос в том, как я могу конвертировать `zoom` полученный на клиенте, в `radius` используемый в запросах на сервере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делать нужно так:

1. Указываем `ref` в `<l-map>`

```
      <no-ssr>
        <l-map
          ref="map"
          :zoom="13"
          :center="[coordinates.lat, coordinates.lng]"
          :options="options"
        >
          <l-tile-layer
            url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <l-marker
            v-for="marker in markers"
            :key="marker.id"
            :lat-lng="[marker.lat, marker.lng]"
          >
            <l-popup>{{ marker.popUpText }}</l-popup>
          </l-marker>
        </l-map>
      </no-ssr>
```

2. Получаем необходимые данные для подсчёта:

```
      let map = this.$refs.map.mapObject
      center = map.getCenter()
      zoom = map.getZoom()
      bounds = map.getBounds()
      let boundNorthEast = bounds.getSouthWest()
      let distance = boundNorthEast.distanceTo(center)
      let radius = distance / 1000
      let latitude = center.lat
      let longitude = center.lng
```

Ну а далее, отправляем данные на сервер.